# Initializing an array of subclass objects creates a heterogeneous superclass array

Tags: matlab, oop

In Matlab, I have the two classes

```
classdef A < matlab.mixin.Heterogeneous
    properties
        a;
    end
    methods
        function obj = A(varargin)
           obj.a = 3;
        end
    end
end
```

and

```
classdef B < A
    properties
        b;
    end
    methods
        function obj = B(varargin)
            obj = obj@A(varargin);
            obj.b = 4;
        end
    end
end
```

I now try to initialize an array of length 2 of type `B`:

```
>> objarray(2) = B

objarray = 

  1x2 heterogeneous A (A, B)

  Properties:
    a

  Methods, Superclasses
```

Why does Matlab insist on making it of class A ? And how can I insist that it be of class `B` instead?

EDIT:
Using the debugger it is apparent that Matlab never enters the constructor for `B` when creating `objarray(1)`

Comment: `objarray` seems to already be defined in your environment...try doing `objarray = [B,B];` instead.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by my environment... If you mean workspace/memory then no, it is not already defined. Naturally your suggestion works, but I have a special need for the exact syntax that I'm suggesting.

Answer (score 2):

I've never tried this myself, but I believe that `matlab.mixin.Heterogeneous` has a method `getDefaultScalarElement` that you can implement/override yourself, which will define how to backfill the initial elements of an array when you assign a later element. See about halfway down [this](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/matlab.mixin.heterogeneousclass.html) documentation page for more information.

Comment: Thanks. I've thought about it and, in a sense, it works. Using `getDefaultScalarElement`, I can indeed force the default object from an `A` array to be of class `B`. However, I don't want it to be locked into that case. For example, if I initialise using `objarray(2) = C`, where `C` is another subclass of `A`, then the objarray should be of class C. But the objarray would have to be of class `A` (the root class of `B` and `C`). Nor do I find it a very pretty solution. We must be getting closer though.

Comment: You can also combine this with specifying the `InferiorClasses` attribute for your classes, which define a precedence hierarchy for deciding both method dispatch (in the case of conflicting method names across classes) and class conversion when concatenating objects of different classes. Perhaps that would help?

Comment: Well, it's related, but I don't really want to specify precedence in absolute terms. I want the precedence of constructors to be determined by the right hand side assignment in `objarray(2) = A/B/C`

Comment: @Patrick: in that case, your only option is to declare the array using: `objarray = repmat(B,2,1)`. btw I tried `B.empty` but it didn't help either.

Comment: @Patrick, I think @Amro's suggestion would work, but alternatively you might be able to overload `subsasgn`, which is the underlying method that is invoked when you use a subscripted assignment syntax such as `myarray(n) = foo`. You could perhaps alter it to check the class of the RHS argument and fill with elements of that class. That's not for the faint-hearted, though.

Comment: @Amro, yes, like nneonneo's suggestion, that ought to work, but unfortunately still doesn't quite offer the convenience that I seek in  the suggested syntax.

Comment: @SamRoberts. Good suggestion. As you say, though, not for the faint hearted. I think I will just have to give in and use the syntax suggested by Amro and nneonneo.

Comment: I'm speaking from experience when I say that overloading `subsref` and `subsasgn` for object arrays is almost impossible to get right! You are required to implement all subscript types: `()`, `.`, `{}`, but you will most certainly break some of them, especially when working with object arrays rather than scalars (there are way too many cases of possibly chained subscripts: `obj(2).x{3}.y(4:6)`). You'll also have to be careful about keeping private properties/methods as such with the `obj.x` notation. It is a real mess if you ask me :)